# ntoskrnl.exe BSOD Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe

Already did a memtest and prime95 which passed. 
Here's the dump:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 052216-4781-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 5/22/2016 9:03:08 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041792
Parameter 2       : fffff680`0009b098
Parameter 3       : 00002000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+142780
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+142780
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\052216-4781-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10586
Dump File Size    : 412,292
Dump File Time    : 5/22/2016 9:03:37 PM
==================================================
```

Comment: share the real dmp file, not this useless text. Also run memtest86+ to detect memory issues and pst pictures of CPU-Z (memory and spd tab)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnmp3dxa6k4mfl9/052216-4781-01.dmp?dl=0 
That's the dmp file. 
Already ran memtest86+ with no error detected. 

Link to all CPU-Z pictures:
http://imgur.com/a/nc76k

Comment: any update? does new RAM fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The dmp shows that you have some hardware issue and 1 Bit in memory (`MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT`) is corrupted:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiDeleteVad
03 nt!MiUnmapViewOfSection
04 nt!NtUnmapViewOfSectionEx
05 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
06 nt!KiServiceLinkage
07 win32kbase!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface
08 win32kbase!SURFREF::bDeleteSurface
09 win32kbase!vCleanupSurfaces
0a win32kbase!NtGdiCloseProcess
0b win32kbase!GdiProcessCallout
0c win32kfull!W32pProcessCallout
0d win32kbase!W32CalloutDispatch
0e nt!PsInvokeWin32Callout
0f nt!PspExitThread
10 nt!KiSchedulerApcTerminate
11 nt!KiDeliverApc
12 nt!KiInitiateUserApc
13 nt!KiSystemServiceExit
14 0x0

MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT
```

The Crucial RAM (BLS8G3D1609DS1S00) is not on the [supported memory list](http://download.gigabyte.ru/memory/mb_memory_ga-b85m-ds3h-a.pdf), so this may cause issues. Try a RAM which is supported by the motherboard.

Comment: Is there a list of 16gb(2x8GB) that is compatible?

Comment: look at the linked PDF for tested RAM modules. Also ask the Gigabyte support for supported modules.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/45dxjsdr36l3cb4/052416-4328-01.dmp?dl=0

Another recent crash occurred.

Comment: the same issue. 1 bit is corrupted. Try other RAM

Comment: Will do. I'll report back then.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzcldkvkp0mi2qu/052516-4421-01.dmp?dl=0

New dumpt this time with the error being a SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

Comment: again a memory_corruption. The RAM seams to be incomaptible. Again, try other RAM

Comment: Could it help to check the RAM settings in BIOS? Maybe it's overclocked or not configured to "Auto"

Answer (score 0):

I had this BSOD daily for quite a while.  Was having it with Win 7 as well as after I changed to Win 10.  I did all the usual stuff - reseated all hardware using rubbing alcohol to clean contact,  made sure all the drivers were up to date, etc.  Ran mem86 test numerous times overnight with no errors detected.  Did my C drive test (have a 500 GB SSD), which reported no errors.  Ran Samsung diagnostics on the SSD, with no errors.

I suspected based on commit charge increasing (monitored using taskmgr) that there was a problem between the 8 GB RAM installed and the paging file usage.  If you track memory usage you can see it increases over time, eventually using the paging file.  When I loaded lots of apps like Picassa and Chrome (neither of which seem to handle memory very well and slowly increase memory consumption), BSOD happened sooner rather than later.  SO I decided to purchase an additional 8 GB of RAM and when it arrived I installed the new memory in place of the old memory and moved the old memory to the empty slots.  Since then (now about 10 days) no BSOD and the system is stable even when I overload it with apps and commit charge grows beyond 8 GB.   Posting this in hopes someone else can solve their BSOD problem.   BTW, diagnostics for BSOD continue to be hopelessly inadequate and ultimately you have to just keep trying things until problem is solved.   Had persistent BSOD about 10 years ago with Windows 2000 system and in that case also RAM was the issue, RAM just went occasionally bad, was fixed with new RAM.